# Python Pyrebase Error: TypeError: 'set' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, pyrebase

I am new to Python and Pyrebase4. When I created my `firebaseConfig` after `pip install pyrebase4`, I ran it just to check whether its working or not and it gave me this `Traceback`

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python Projects\FirebaseTesting\main.py", line 14, in <module>
    firebase = pyrebase.initialize_app(firebaseConfig)
  File "D:\Python Projects\FirebaseTesting\venv\lib\site-packages\pyrebase\pyrebase.py", line 28, in initialize_app
    return Firebase(config)
  File "D:\Python Projects\FirebaseTesting\venv\lib\site-packages\pyrebase\pyrebase.py", line 34, in __init__
    self.api_key = config["apiKey"]
TypeError: 'set' object is not subscriptable
```

Here is My Code:

```
import pyrebase

firebaseConfig = { 'apiKey:' "xxx",
  'authDomain:' "xxx.firebaseapp.com",
  'databaseURL:' "https://xxx-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com",
  'projectId:' "xxx",
  'storageBucket:' "xxx.appspot.com",
  'messagingSenderId:' "xxx",
  'appId:' "xxx",
  'measurementId:' "xxx"}

firebase = pyrebase.initialize_app(firebaseConfig)
```

Please Help Me Out! It would be greatly helpful

Thanks

Programmer_Steve

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should fix your problem:

```
firebaseConfig = { 'apiKey': "xxx",
  'authDomain': "xxx.firebaseapp.com",
  'databaseURL': "https://xxx-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com",
  'projectId': "xxx",
  'storageBucket': "xxx.appspot.com",
  'messagingSenderId': "xxx",
  'appId': "xxx",
  'measurementId': "xxx"}
```

*Notice that `:` is outside!!*

What you were doing is like this: `a = {"a:", "b", "c:", "d"}`, and this is called a set in Python. I'm pretty sure you were trying to create a dictionary, and a dictionary can be created like this: `a = {"a": "b", "c": "b"}`.
Can you see the difference?

The difference is that you were putting `:` inside `"`, and Python thinks `:` is part of the string.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is of course correct, `set` objects aren't subscriptable.  But dictionaries are, and they're very similar.  In your case you made the very simple mistake of putting the `:` inside the string instead of outside, resulting in a set when you wanted a dictionary.